# what are the purpose of different types of assembly registers?

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

*Assume this is in AT&T syntax.*

When there is a question such as:

```
movl (%rdi), %ecx
```

What is the purpose of `%rdi` or `%ecx`?

I understand the concept of `mov(q,l,w,b)` or `add(q,l,w,b)` and so on.

Can we write `%rdx` instead of `%rdi`?  If so, what would that change? Why does `%rdi` exist?

Comment: `rdi` is an actual register, which is different from `rdx`. `rdi` is the daddy of `edi`, grand-daddy of `di`, and the brother of `rsi`. `rdi` and `rsi` once stood for Destination and Source Index registers, but nowadays can generally be used like the other general-purpose registers. However, `rdi` doesn't have an equivalent to DX's 8-bit upper half (DH).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist can you elaborate more? OK I understand %rdi is actual register. What do you mean by " Which is different from rdx" ? why is it different?

Comment: It literally refers to a different register. If I store something to `rdi` it's not stored in `rdx`, and `rdx` remains unchanged. Here: http://www.ntcore.com/files/vista_x64/x64_registers.jpg

Comment: You're a victim of using Intel architecture CPUs - theirs have been rather notorious about attributing different capabilities and functions to different registers, though it is not as bad any longer than it once was, in pre-386 times.

Comment: It's mostly historical, although some instructions are still tied to specific registers, such as movs... where rsi (or ds:esi) contains the source address and rdi (or es:edi) is the destination address. Loop instruction uses rcx / ecx.

Comment: Going back to the 8008, an 8 bit processor, H and L registers were combined for 16 bit addressing. There was only an 8 bit accumulator A. When the 8088/8086 was released, the standard for translation was A=>AL, B=>CH, C=>CL, H=>BH, L=>BL, D=>DH, E=>DL. SI and DI were added. 64 bit mode just named the new registers R8, R9, ... .

Answer (score 16):

x86_64 has 16 general-purpose registers. 8 are carried over from x86 (eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi, edi, ebp, esp), and 8 are brand new (r8 through r15).

In past days, registers had very specific functions.

- `eax` was the accumulator register on which you principally did arithmetic
- `ebx` was the base register from which you did memory address calculations
- `ecx` was the count register which held a loop counter
- `edx` was the data register which you could use for I/O port access
- `edi` was the destination index register which pointed to the "destination" of a string operation
- `esi` was the source index register which pointed to the "source" of a string operation
- `ebp` was the base pointer which pointed to the base of the current stack frame.
- `esp` was the stack pointer.

Initially, when the instruction set was tiny, certain instructions would only operate with certain registers. For example, `rep stos` instructions use `ECX` as a counter and stored data into the memory pointed to by `EDI`.

Nowadays, specialized instructions like that are not as commonly seen, and the instructions which are used nowadays by compilers generally accept any of the general purpose registers. So, these days, you can basically treat the CPU as having 14 registers which are almost fully interchangeable (note that `ebp` and `esp` are still used as the base pointer and stack pointer, and are often not usable for other purposes).

Comment: 386 orthogonalized (does that verb exist?) the architecture a lot. So, the registers which had very specific functions were (in 8086) `AX, BX, CX, DX, DI, SI, BP, SP, FLAGS, IP`, some of which inherited the functions of some registers in 8080, which inherited from 8008. In 386+ you can pretty much use any register almost anywhere.

Comment: My experience with 386 is that there were still a number of fairly useful opcodes which had specific limitations on the registers. For example, `IMUL` produces results only in `EDX:EAX`, `REP` and friends only use `ECX` for counting, and a few others that I've forgotten due to the fog of time. x86_64 seems to be better in this regard because it permits r8-r15 in a lot of contexts.

Comment: (Not to say that 386 wasn't an improvement over 8086...reading 8086 assembly kinda sucks because of implicit registers, and writing it sucks even more).

Comment: (One could say that the x86 has been morphing from an accumulator based architecture to a register-file based architecture, 8086 being less acculumator-y than its predecessors (8080 adds and subs being always on the accumulator), and 80386 being relatively very register-file-y).